# App Insights Undefined Entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I am using app insights in my web forms application and I get always entries with undefined description equal to the entities with named descritions.

Here is a snapshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTKvZ.jpg

Always I get entries like this:

1. Why is the undefined tag count equal to the Windows 10 tag (almost always)?
2. What does the undefined tag mean, does it mean that the app insights has failed to recognize the operating system?

Is it because the undefined things are from the server side because I see many dependency calls to DATABASE and only POST requests when I further explore the  tag's row.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it only the events coming from the back end that have the undefined description ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes  means Application Insights failed to recognize the operating system.  THe reason it is equal to Windows10 tag looks purely coincidental.